# Why does the GEt_stocks endpoint from Telecope Analytics cause an error?

Tags: analytics, rapidapi, telescope

At the RapidApi.com website I am using the Telescope API to retreive information about stocks (I am a subscribed user).
This API offers three endpoints.

The endpoints "GET opitons" and "GET price" are working fine while the endpoint "GET stocks" retunrs an error message

```
 code:"Unauthorized"

 description:"Invalid Cookie"
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Telescope Analytics offers the possibility to test the endpoints on its website. When testing the endpoint "GET_stocks", I receive the error message described.

Comment: Based on what you described, it seems you need a login credential for this to work, an API KEY perhaps? Invalid Cookie would mean your current login credential/session is no longer valid that is why it is not allowing you to get results.

Comment: I am trying it from the RapidApi Website, where I have to login to get access to the Telescope API.
I can successfully retrieve data from the GET_options and GET_price endpoints but not from the GET_stocks endpoint